# getting the analysis of an online webgame

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have created a simple table tennis game in jquery.
I have hosted on the server for the users to play the game.
Now what I want to do is to analyse the statistics of the game.
Basically what I want to do is to record the time for the users to complete the game and store them in the database and periodically perform the analysis like average time for completion, etc.
Where I am getting stuck is how to control the execution of the javascript and starting a timer to record the time needed for game completion and at the end of the game passing it on?

or should I just add a timer in the game itself recording time and thereafter on completion it would pass on the data to server and update the database?

Comment: Your question is way too vague for anybody to answer. In general, I'd guess start a timer when the game starts (when the player clicks start or whatever) and when the game finishes post it to a webservice that will write to the database.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't add the timer to the javascript, as it could be manipulated by the user. I would register the start of the game with an AJAX call to a script that puts a start time in the database for that game, and then when the game is completed, do another AJAX call to mark the end time.

Comment: Good point. If the data is important enough, then marking time on the server will be more secure. However, you will need to be tolerant of the fact that some people aren't going to finish, so you'll need some kind of clean up. Also, don't think that this will automatically make it unhackable because, of course, it won't. Those AJAX calls could be manipulated directly from the console as well.

Comment: Good on both points. I assume there is much more complexity than just what is stated in the question. The AJAX calls can be manipulated from the console (or through other methods), but that can be managed with some sort of token/other security method, and there are even plugins/classes that solve that issue.

Comment: thanks for the input.... will surely try it out....